# Can i Log all the jobs(documents) comes to print in c# like a service?

Tags: c#, service, window, printers

I know, I am just asking a question without trying any code, but I am bit confused if it is possible or not. I have a printer installed on the network, I want to get which person has sent the print command. means who has used the printer, their IP and the no of pages and the datetime of the print job. Is successfully completed or not.

Is it possible to get this info?

Answer (score 1):

Windows can log print jobs, but it is turned off by default.  You can see it in eventviewer under Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Print Service -> Operational. [image]

You can read windows logs using the System.Diagnostics.EventLog class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4857/A-realtime-event-log-monitoring-tool